# Difference between あったんだった and あったんだ

Tags: grammar, modality

1. 

> A「お昼休みなのに忙しそうだね」
>
> B「午後から会議があるんだ」
>
> A「ずいぶんゆっくりしてるけど、大丈夫？」
>
> B「あっ、そうか！今日は午後から会議が**あったんだった**」

2. 

> A「今日一緒にご飯に行かない？」
>
> B「ごめん、今日は彼女との予定があるんだ」
>
> B「ごめん！さっき外食する約束をしたけど、今日は別の予定が**あったんだ**」

Here are two dialogues. What would be the difference between あったんだった and あったんだ?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/40733/5010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This use of た is called modal-ta or 発見のタ. There are a number of questions related to this on this site.

- [Non conventional usage of the past tense](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/40733/5010)

  > "fixing (or updating) one's previous knowledge/expectation" seems to be the key
- [Usage of plain i-adjectives or た form (悪かったｖ悪い、良かったｖいい etc）](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21347/5010)

  > It is used when one's expectation has just matched or failed to match reality.
- [Conjugated word + んだ vs nonconjugated word + conjugated んだ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/60788/5010)

In Dialog 1, B is updating his own knowledge, and that's why the sentence ends with the modal-ta. But 会議があったんだった sounds a little redundant to me. 会議があるんだった is equally correct and probably more common.

In Dialog 2, B is trying to update A's knowledge by telling what is already known to B, so the sentence must not end with the modal-ta. 別の予定があるんだ and 別の予定があったんだ are equally correct, but the latter contains a modal-ta before the end of the sentence to update A's knowledge; it implies "(I know) this is not what you've expected".

Answer (score 2):

In such cases, there are two relevant differences to consider:

- is a piece of information known to the speaker or not?
- who does the information come from?

In the first scenario, in which two co-workers talk about a conference, B already knew that a conference was to take place on that particular day. They simply seem to have forgotten and are now re-establishing this knowledge. In that case, the original information about the conference came from A and is now re-stated by B.

In the second scenario, the information that B already has plans is new information to A. Therefore, it is in the present tense, as B is offering this new piece of information to A just now.